# How to correctly compute cumulative distribution on sample dataset

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider the following table and data set.

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE(
  "Group" TEXT,
  Callees INTEGER,
  Callers INTEGER
  );
  
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("Group", Callees, Callers) VALUES ('Group1', 1, 505);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("Group", Callees, Callers) VALUES ('Group1', 2, 172);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("Group", Callees, Callers) VALUES ('Group1', 3, 33);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("Group", Callees, Callers) VALUES ('Group1', 4, 20);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("Group", Callees, Callers) VALUES ('Group1', 5, 5);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("Group", Callees, Callers) VALUES ('Group1', 6, 5);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("Group", Callees, Callers) VALUES ('Group1', 7, 3);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("Group", Callees, Callers) VALUES ('Group1', 8, 4);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("Group", Callees, Callers) VALUES ('Group1', 9, 3);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("Group", Callees, Callers) VALUES ('Group1', 10, 2);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("Group", Callees, Callers) VALUES ('Group1', 11, 1);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("Group", Callees, Callers) VALUES ('Group1', 13, 1);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("Group", Callees, Callers) VALUES ('Group1', 14, 1);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("Group", Callees, Callers) VALUES ('Group1', 16, 1);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("Group", Callees, Callers) VALUES ('Group1', 22, 2);
```

I want to create a cumulative distribution that shows cumulative % of total Callers based on the values in the Callees column, for the group. For example, for the value Callees = 1, I would like the first output row:

```
Group1  1 505 0.6662
Group1  2 172 0.8931
Group1  3  33 0.9366
...
Group1 22   1 1.0000
```

Where 0.6662 is 505 divided by total number of Callers, 758.Then the following rows should would contain the cumulative percentage as we go down the Callees column values.

I tried:

```
select "Group", Callers,
cume_dist() over ( order by Callees desc) as CumulativeP
from MY_TABLE
order by "Group", Callees
```

But it does not give me the output I want. How can I make this happen?

I am using SQLite 3.3x

Comment: @NishantGupta I added some more rows to clarify. It's a cumulative distribution, it answers the question, what percentage of Callers have X Callees or less. For example, if you look at the first row I provided, it says 66.62% of Callers have contacted 1 Callee or less.

Comment: **Thank you** for providing SQL to create a sample table instead of ascii art or an image of the data! I wish more people did that.

Comment: Except `Group` is a SQL keyword and needs to be escaped - `"Group"`.

Comment: Are you sure about the version of SQLite? Did you mean 3.30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for your problem:

```
select "Group", Callees,mt.Callers,
ROUND((sum(callers) over(Partition By "Group" order by Callees) * 1.00) / (sum(callers) over (Partition By "Group" RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)),4) CumulativeP
from MY_TABLE mt
order by "Group", Callees;
```

Working Example: [db fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e0b262d97462feb3306dc2875840084f)

**Explanation:**
`Window` function contains `Window Frame` to define the number of rows or the range that should be included by the function for calculation. 
For example, to calculate cumulative sum, the sum should  be applied from the first row till the current row for each row.
Now to calculate the sum over the whole table or for all rows (Within the defined partition), the range should be from first row to the last row of the table(or the partition if defined) and this can be defined with `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` (which tells to take the rows from the first row of the table or partition) and 'UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING' (which tell to take the rows till the last one in the table or partition).

 Syntaxes of the `Window Frame` are:

```
( GROUPS | RANGE | ROWS ) start

(GROUPS | RANGE | ROWS ) BETWEEN start AND end
```

Where start can be:

```
UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
expr PRECEDING
CURRENT ROW
expr FOLLOWING
```

and end can be:

```
expr PRECEDING
CURRENT ROW
UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
expr FOLLOWING
```

For more info on `Window Function` please see the below link:

[Official Document](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html)

For better understanding about `Window Frame`, follow below link:

[Sqlite window frame](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-window-frame/)

Comment: Thanks for your proposed solution, Nishant. Could you elaborate in your answer on what the query is doing and why? In particular, I would want (sum(callers) over (Partition By "Group" RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)),4) explained.

Comment: I tried to explain it. If it is not clear please let me know I will try to explain it in more easier way.

Comment: Since you have the PARTITION BY, why do you need to specify RANGE? Is it not implied by the values in the rows of the partition? @Nishant Gupta

Comment: @ragnacode the default range for `SUM` function with `Window` function is `Between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` which needs to be changed to the `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` to get the `Total Sum` of the all rows within a partition, otherwise I would get the same result as the one I got in the case of cumulative one. Have you gone through the working example, I have updated it for better understanding.

Comment: I did and I found that removing the RANGE statement it does not make a difference in the output. Perhaps the data is not sufficient to elicit the incorrect behavior?

Comment: Since `ORDER BY` clause is not used for total_sum in `SUM` window function hence, it took all the rows in each partition and summed them together. You can remove `Range` clause or you can keep it. It doesn't make any difference. If you wanna know more about it you can go through `Section 3 Built-In-Window function` of the above official doc link I shared in my answer and search for `Order BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. I learned a lot from your answer.